# Unbind and Bind click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery which has previous and next buttons. So inorder to make the images change I have written a function which keeps on clicking the next button to change the image.

```
function infiniteLoop(time){
    function f(){
        $('.image-nav-next').click() // click the next button
        timer = setTimeout(f, time)
    }
    f();
}
```

This works fine for me. But now I want to pause the click event on image hover. Meaning, when the user hovers on the image in the gallery then it should show the same image as long as the mouse is over that image. When the user removes the cursor from the image then the gallery again starts working and changing the image as before. I tried the following-

```
$('.myimg').mouseover(function(){         
    $('.image-nav-next').unbind('click');
});
```

and then

```
$('.myimg').mouseout(function(){          
    $('.image-nav-next').bind('click');
});
```

Unbind works fine but then the re bind does not work. Any Idea?

Comment: Instead you need to clear the timer and on mouseout again call the `infiniteLoop` function

Comment: @Arun, is it something like this ? clearTimeout(timer)

Comment: Wow.. That's works. I tried it before but I was doing it in a slight wrong way. If you can just create an answer I will be happy enough to accept that s correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going the wrong way about it.

Instead what you need to do is to clear the timer on mouse enter `clearTimeout(timer)`, and on mouse leave you can again schedule the looping by calling `infiniteLoop`

Comment: Can you just tell me why does the bind click event does not work?
`$('.image-nav-next').bind('click');`

Comment: @Illusion The bind method will require the function to be called as a parameter